# Dragging and dropping not working in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm working on my first Swift project in Xcode and am running into trouble with dragging and dropping elements from the storyboard into the code.

Nothing happens when I try dragging and dropping. I'm running the newest version of Xcode and using Swift.

The class is **ViewController** and the file is **ViewController.swift**

I'm trying to drag and drop a textfield into the class.

Comment: Are you holding Control?

Comment: Yes, I'm holding control and dragging. No blue line shows up if that helps.

Comment: Did you set the class in identity inspector to match the class for the viewcontroller?

Comment: I chose the automatic option and it had the name of file: ViewController.swift

Comment: Please refer to following documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson3.html.

Comment: Are you trying to put an actual UI element into your code or are you trying to create an outlet?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'll check it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a question and possible solution for you, Sam.

What system are you using to do this? When I first started I wanted to use a mac over a remote connection and I found that holding control and dragging yielded me no blue line to associate the Interface Builder items with the assistant editor's code. I tried Chrome remote desktop, splash top, and VNC viewer. Nothing yielded the results I was looking for. Only when I got my own mac and was working with the machine itself was I able to control-click-and-drag to associate Interface Builder items with code.

Also, are you using the assistant editor or dragging into the file in the navigator on the left? I haven't tried the latter... only ever used the assistant editor.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm using a Mac Air on my local machine. I'm also using the assistant editor. If you have anymore ideas, I would appreciate it. I'm at a loss as to what to do.

Comment: Only other thing I would recommend (which you're probably already doing) is selecting the item you want to drag over so that its isolated from everything else. I accidentally linked my entire view controller to code once and that was sure a lot of fun. Are you using the touchpad or a mouse? Also, I know there's some settings in Xcode preferences for keys and other software functions so if there's a specific term or option for that type of operation maybe it's disabled? I'll look into that more now.

Comment: Sorry to keep posting so much, but I'm determined lol. Anyway, I was pawing through Xcode documentation for the outlet menus and I saw that you can "view" the outlet connections by control clicking the item that you're looking to connect. Not control-drag but just control click. I'm curious to see if just control clicking allows you to see the connection menu. If it doesn't, than maybe your control key isn't working properly? 

You can find that in the documentation for "Managing a user interface option's connections" and from the menu, you can click and drag fromt he item to assist. editor.

Comment: So I tried "control clicking" and it didn't work. I than tried using both fingers to click instead of just one (using the touchpad) and it worked. I than tried clicking with two fingers and dragging and that worked as well. So, I'm all good!

Comment: That's awesome! I would maybe look into how your touchpad gestures are setup, or if there's specific keyboard settings for the mac that control how the "control" key are operated. The documentation is designed for the use of that key, so it's interesting that it worked for you the way that it does! I'll have to remember that in case I ever run into the same problem. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, Sam J.!  Your two-finger click is the ONLY explanation about this issue that actually worked.  That should be the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

You need to first change the class of the ViewController in the Storyboard to match the class of file that you are dropping into. Click the dropdown menu and choose your own viewcontroller class.

I'd suggest to rename your own viewcontroller class to differentiate it from iOS build-in class. Otherwise you might get confused while selecting the class.

[image]

Comment: I selected the correct class name and just changed the name to make sure that wasn't the issue. I'm still having problems.

Comment: Thanks buddy, you saved me!

Answer (score 0):

May be you already solve. but it may help some one else. for Xcode-10 you will go

> editor -> Localization Locking  -> Reset Locking Controls

it help me to enable dragging and dropping the element.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You drag and drop into the Storyboard (Main.storyboard is the default name).

You cannot drag and drop inside a .swift file.

When your UI is complete, you need to "bind" the storyboard scene with the UIViewController (or any subclass) in the Identity Inspector (check [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-general/Chapters/AbouttheUtilityArea.html))

Comment: I did bind it but it's still not working. Any suggestions would be appreciated